# What is Content Construction Kit (CCK) in Drupal

Tags: entities

What is Content Construction Kit (CCK) in Drupal and what is the purpose of CCK?

Comment: What does it's project page say, and what part of it you don't understand?

Answer (score 3):

It used to be called CCK in Drupal prior to Drupal 7, and came in the shape of a contributed module.  In Drupal 7, most of the functionality of the CCK module was moved into the core and it is now usually referred to as "fields" (or "fields in core").

The purpose of the CCK was to provide a simple UI for adding new "fields" to entities so that new, specific content types could be created by site designers.

In Drupal 7, you do exactly the same thing by adding "fields" (which may be typed) to entities.  A full tutorial about CCK/fields is beyond the scope of this Q+A site, but GIYF (Google Is Your Friend).

**Edit:** As noted in a comment by [jimajamma](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/4255/jimajamma), the [CCK project page](https://drupal.org/project/cck) has more information and links to tutorials.

Comment: Indeed, https://drupal.org/project/cck and any of the links therein if one's googlefu is not up to snuff